# Erlang for each list of lists

Tags: list, foreach, erlang

I want to make a new list that only contains the elements of the "list of lists" which have a length of 1.

The code that i provide gives a exception error: no function clause matching.

```
lists:foreach(fun(X) if length(X) =:= 1 -> [X] end, ListOfLists).
```

I am new to erlang, and I am having trouble finding an alternative way for writing this piece of code.

Can someone give me some advice on how to do so?

Comment: A simple list comprehension will do: [L || L <- ListOfLists, length(L) == 1].

Comment: I just realized how pointless my initial explanation may have been if you're really new to Erlang and functional programming. I expanded my answer a bit more with some discussion about ways you might accomplish this and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match in a list comprehension to get this quite naturally:

```
[L || L = [_] <- ListOfLists]
```

For example:

```
1> LoL = [[a], [b,c], d, [e], [f,g]].
[[a],[b,c],d,[e],[f,g]]
2> [L || L = [_] <- LoL].
[[a],[e]]
```

If you want the elements themselves (as in result `[a, e]` instead of `[[a], [e]]`) you can match on the element within the shape:

```
3> [L || [L] <- LoL].    
[a,e]
```

Depending on the size of the lists contained within `LoL`, matching will be significantly faster than calling `length/1` on every member. Calling `length/1` and then testing the result requires traversing the entire list, returning a value, and then testing it.  This is arbitrarily more overhead than checking if the second element of the list is a termination (in other words, if the "shape" of the data matches).

**Regarding your attempt above...**

As a newcomer to Erlang it might be helpful to become familiar with the basic functional list operations. They pop up over and over in functional (and logic) programming, and generally have the same names. "maps", "folds", "filters", "cons", "car" ("head" or "hd" or `[X|_]`), "cdr" ("tail" or "tl" or `[_|X]`), and so on.

Your original attempt:

```
lists:foreach(fun(X) if length(X) =:= 1 -> [X] end, ListOfLists).
```

This can't work because `foreach/2` only returns `ok`, never any value. It is used *only* when you want to iterate over a list to get *side-effects*, not because you want to get a return value. For example, if I have a chat system the chat rooms have a list of current members, and broadcasting a message is really sending each chat message to each member in the list, I might do:

```
-spec broadcast(list(), unicode:chardata()) -> ok.
broadcast(Users, Message) ->
    Forward = fun(User) -> send(User, Message) end,
    lists:foreach(Forward, Users).
```

I don't care about the return value, really, and we aren't changing anything in the list `Users` or the `Message`. (Note that here we are using the anonymous function to *capture the relevant state* that it requires -- essentially currying out the `Message` value so we can present a function of arity 1 to the list operation `foreach/2`. This is where lambdas become most useful in Erlang vs named functions.)

When you want to take a list as an input and return a single, aggregate value (use some operation to roll all the values in the list into one) you can use a fold (you almost always want to use `foldl/3`, specifically):

```
4> lists:foldl(fun(X, A) when length(X) =:= 1 -> [X|A]; (_, A) -> A end, [], LoL).
[[e],[a]]
```

Broken down that reads as:

```
Single =
    fun
        (X, A) when length(X) =:= 1 -> [X|A];
        (_, A) -> [X|A]
    end,
ListOfSingles = lists:foldl(Single, [], LoL).
```

This is an anonymous function that has two clauses.

Written another way with a case we could do:

```
Single =
    fun(X, A) ->
        case length(X) of
            1 -> [X|A];
            _ -> A
        end
    end,
```

This is a matter of preference, as is the choice to inline that as an anonymous function within the call to `foldl/3`.

What you are *really* trying to do, though, is *filter* the list, and there is a universal list function called just that. You supply a testing function that returns a boolean -- if the test is true then the element will turn up in the output, otherwise it will not:

```
5> lists:filter(fun([X]) -> true; (_) -> false end, LoL).
[[a],[e]]
```

Breaking the lambda out as before:

```
6> Single =
6>     fun([X]) -> true;
6>        (_)   -> false
6>     end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
7> lists:filter(Single, LoL).
[[a],[e]]
```

Here we matched on the shape of the element in the anonymous function head. This filter is almost *exactly* equivalent to the list comprehension above (the only difference, really, is in the underlying implementation of list comprehensions -- semantically they are identical).

Comment: Well, now my answer is redundant :)

Comment: @bob If you're new to programming swing by #erlang on IRC, visit the [Erlang chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75358/erlang-otp) here on SO, and check out the [erlang-questions](http://www.erlang.org/static/doc/mailinglist.html) mailing list. They are all fairly low-volume. Erlang is actually pretty nice first language, though it *does* have a tendency to spoil people. Also, this is invaluable if you have time [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I totally missed it (dove back into the editor once I realized the OP probably needed more context). Deleted?

Comment: @zxq9 Yes, I saw the non-edited version of your answer first and it was edited by the time I finished.

Comment: @zxq9 Thnx for the additional info.